# Number of max rules for CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN?

Tags: hunspell

I have this affix and dic file that is working as expected.

```
cat sa_IN.aff

SET UTF-8
COMPOUNDFLAG X
MAXCPDSUGS 0

CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN 1
CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN त् अ द
```

And the wordlist...

```
cat sa_IN.dic

2
आश्रयेत्/X
अस्मान्/X
```

This word is considered correct.

```
spellchecker.spell('आश्रयेदस्मान्')
```

But if I add rules to CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN flag then the same  word is marked as incorrect. Is there a limit on CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN?

How many rules are allowed?

---

Update:

If I read the first 31452 lines then both the words return True.

```
spellchecker.spell('अस्मानाश्रयेत्')
spellchecker.spell('आश्रयेदस्मान्')
```

But if I add next 1000 lines, then both the words return False.

```
CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN 32452
```

Does it mean there is some problem between 31 and 32 thousand lines?

The affix file is available here...

https://github.com/shantanuo/stack_question/blob/master/sa_IN.aff

---

Using this python code. I have also checked using firefox extension and I am getting same results in both.

```
import hunspell

spellchecker = hunspell.HunSpell(
    "./sa_IN.dic",
    "./sa_IN.aff",
)

spellchecker.spell('अस्मानाश्रयेत्')
```